# When is this function constant?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a smooth map $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ $$(x,y)\rightarrow f(x,y)$$
with the following property:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{y=y_0}=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{y=y_0}$$
for some point $y_0\in \mathbb{R}$.

Does it then follow that at $y=y_0$, $f(x,y)$ is independent of $x$? That is, do we have $$\frac{\partial (f(x,y_0))}{\partial x}=0$$

Comment: When you say “for some point $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$”, do you also mean “...and for all $x  \in \mathbb{R}$”? In that case, your conclusion is exacly the same as (the $\partial f/\partial x$ half of) the hypothesis, isn't it?